# Why is Internet Addiction Disorder not listed in the DSM-5 manual?

Tags: internet, addiction

Disclaimer - I am not a student of psychology.

I'm currently researching Internet Addiction Disorder and online games for a paper I'm writing. Is there an actual reason why it's not included? Is it because it's such a new area of study?

Comment: From my experience looking into the subject in 2010, there's little interest in internet or video game addiction research. Many people may agree that in 2016 we are looking at smartphone addiction as a massive issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's debate over whether Internet addiction is it's own disorder or a symptom of an underlying psychosis. See this essay by the first man to publish the term: https://theconversation.com/is-internet-addiction-a-misnomer-55727

Comment: If you elaborate on this (including a further short description of the source you link to, and preferably linking directly to the study it reports on as well), this could be a suitable answer.